# What is the load() method in Guava LoadingCache?

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava

I am trying to implement the LoadingCache and in it I must override the load() method.

However, the documentation is a bit lacking and I can't seem to find any decent examples surrounding this. My questions for this are:

- What does it do?
- When is it called?
- How often is it called?

Comment: Do you really **need** to implement `LoadingCache` yourself? Have you tried using [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) instead? (It creates `LoadingCache` for you.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`LoadingCache`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html) doesn't have a `load()` method, [`CacheLoader`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html) does. And if you read the [CachesExplained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) page of the wiki in addition to the javadoc, I think there's plenty of documentation:

- A `LoadingCache` will automatically compute values it doesn't already have (because they never were requested, or were evicted) when they are requested by key.
- To do so, it delegates the computation to the `CacheLoader` which given a key, returns the value: that's the job of the `V load(K key)` method, the only abstract method of `CacheLoader`, the one you need to implement.